# Implementation authorization and authentication for AngularJS with OAuth.io

Tags: angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0

Please tell me an example of implementation of authorization and authentication for AngularJS with [OAuth.io](https://oauth.io/).

Comment: At that moment I did not know where to start.. Therefore, the question is not formalized. But I take your remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On these [slides](http://slid.es/arnaudrichard/angular-oauth-io), you can find some samples code for Angular with OAuth.io (Twitter timeline + a synchronization of Google drive with Dropbox)

Comment: Hi, i m the author of these slides, there is a big part in french so you can directly skip to the examples part

Comment: Thanks. I have not seen these slides. This is a good starting point)